# VirtualBox 5 - Win 7 or 8 guests: Graphics Adapter that will allow free upgrade to Win 10

Tags: macos, virtualbox, graphics-card, windows-10-upgrade

I had two machines: 
OSX Yosimite with VirtualBox 4.3 and a Win 7 guest 
OSX Yosimite with VirtualBox 4.3 and a Win 8.1 guest

Both had the Win 10 upgrade icon but they both said "Unfortunately, this PC is unable to run Windows 10.". It cites a compatability issue with the VirtualBox Graphics Adapter for Windows (both 7 and 8).

I upgraded to El Capitan and Virtual Box 5 on one and I upgraded to VirtualBox 5 on Yosimite for the other but have the same message on both.

Anybody know how I can get a Graphics Adapter for VirtualBox 5 that will let me upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: Don't install the GuestAdditions. Let Windows use the Standard VGA driver. That would be my first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread in the VirtualBox.org forum from Rootman. He provided a link to the Windows Media Creation Tool that was easy to use and made the update. You can do an upgrade and if you want you can then do a Reset from the Settings app to do a clean install.

The tool is at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Good luck -  it worked for me and had no issue with the VirtualBox graphics adapter.